# the first digits of a normal number

Tags: probability, number-theory

We will say that x, a number between 0 and 1 written in base 2, is a good number if at least one of those statements is true for him:

statement 1: the sequence '0' appears in the first 2 digits of x (in base 2)
statement 2: the sequence '00' appears in the first 4 digits of x (in base 2)
statement 3: the sequence '000' appears in the first 8 digits of x (in base 2)
.
.
.
statement n: the sequence '0...0'(n zero's) appears in the first 2^n digits of x (in base 2)
.
.

my question is: Is every normal number in base 2 between 0 and 1 a good number?

(for the normal number in base b definition, you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)

Comment: The decimal expansion of a normal number could begin with a string of a googolplex number of $1$'s.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The number is written in base $2$.

Comment: @Nilknarf then reword his statement in terms of base2 normal numbers... a normal number in base2 could start with a googolplex number of $1$'s.  The definition of normality makes absolutely no reference to what happens within the first however many finite number of digits.

Comment: @Nilknarf: Thanks! I've fixed it.

Comment: @JMoravitz But the number $0.\overline{1}_2$ is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...=1=1_2$$

Comment: What I said earlier is also true for much weaker notions than that of being a normal number, such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence).

Comment: @Nilknarf yes... and we are not talking about that number... the number dave and I refer to eventually have zeroes.  We are talking about some number of the form $0.\underbrace{111\cdots 1}_{10^{10^{100}}~\text{ones}}\underbrace{xxx\cdots x}_{\text{other stuff}}$.  That other stuff at the end could be all that is needed to make it a normal number.  In fact, if you were to look only at those digits after the prescribed sequence of ones at the start, so long as that number $0.xxxx\dots$ is normal, then so too is the number we describe.  Do not confuse infinity with a finite large number.

Comment: Try concatentating something like 1, 1, 0, 11, 10, 01, 00, 111, 110, 101, 100, 011, 010, 001, 000, 1111, ... (pattern should be obvious).  I would guess this is a normal number base $2$ but the first appearance of $n$ consecutive 0s is after position $2^n$.  For "0" it is position $3$; for "00" it is positions $7$ and $8$ ; for "000" it is positions $22-24$; and so on

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro you didn't answered my question.  The first googolplex digits aren't matter.

Comment: @D.hershko we did answer your question.  We gave a general example of a normal number which is not a "good" number.  If you prefer a smaller, easier to understand example, take your favorite normal number $x$ and add two 1's at the front of it.  The resulting number, $0.11 + 0.01x$ is again normal. but does not satisfy the properties of being a "good number" since the sequence "0" does not appear in the first two digits.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Let me make another question:

Comment: statement n will be: n zero's appears in the first a(n) digits of n, when 2^n is little-O of a(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) base $2$ which results from concatenating the binary positive integers $1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,\ldots$: $$C_2=0.1101110010111011110001001101010111100110111101111100001000110010\ldots_2$$

$C_2$ is a normal number base $2$ (Nakai, Y.; Shiokawa, I. 1992) despite finite partial lists having more $1$s then $0$s

The string "$00\ldots 0$" with $n$ zeros first appears starting in position $3+(n-1)2^n$ of $C_2$, which is greater than $2^n$ for all positive integers $n$ and grows faster thanks to the $(n-1)$ term.  This sequence of starting positions is $3, 7, 19, 51, 131, \ldots$

So $C_2$ is not *good* under your definition, but is normal in base $2$.  Something similar can be shown for other bases, using their corresponding  Champernowne constants